# NoClassDefFoundError in jackcess

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jackcess

I am working on an RCP application which is based on eclipse plugins. In one of my plugin project I add another plugin project as dependency. Let say Project A has  Project B as a dependency defined under its manifest. Project B contains jackcess.jar file as referenced library.

In Project B I have a class called Mirror.java

```
 public Mirror(String source, String template, String target) throws SQLException, IOException {
    this.sourceString=source;
    this.templateFileString=template;
    this.targetFileString=target;
}
```

inside from project A when I try to create an object of class Mirror

```
 Mirror  m = new Mirror(connectionString, "EABase_JET4_empty.eap",platformDB.getAbsolutePath());
```

I get the following error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/ImportFilter

build.properties of Project B (containing jackcess.jar)

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           src/main/resources/lib/jackcess-1.2.6.af3.jar
```

The MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MirrorDbToEap
Bundle-SymbolicName: MirrorDbToEap
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package: .,
 com.example.jetdb.mirror
 Require-Bundle: CommonsIo;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 org.apache.commons.lang;bundle-version="2.6.0",
 org.apache.commons.logging;bundle-version="1.0.4"
```

[image]
Anyone having any idea what's going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the build.properties and MANIFEST.MF files for the project containing jackcess.jar

Comment: @greg-449Check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including the jackcess.jar in the bin.includes in the build.properties file so it is not being included in the RCP build.

Open the build.properties editor and select the jar in the 'Binary Build' selection.

The jar must also appear in the `Bundle-ClassPath` in the MANIFEST.MF. In the manifest editor in the Runtime tab add the jar to the 'Classpath' section (you should also have '.' for normal plugin code).

Comment: its still giving me the same error my build.properties look like this now bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               src/main/resources/lib/jackcess-1.2.6.af3.jar

Comment: Please edit the question and put the new build.properties there, it is impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: I also attached an image

Comment: Added Bundle-ClassPath requirement

Answer (score 0):

It seems the class which is available in compile time, is not available in run time.

Comment: yes I know but how can I add this class during the runtime , is it not enough to add the project B as dependency in project A ?

Comment: I think so, that would be enough